# Is there a replacement for initState and didChangeDependencies methods for Stateless Widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't have any code to show just a question which makes me keep thinking of a better approach, every time I need to load data before rendering it to the image. I use initState or didChangeDependencies methods for that, but to keep that I've to make the whole widget stateful to access these methods.

So my question is there a better approach for Stateless Widgets not to be converted to Stateful and still get the same results are same.

I tried finding some results but couldn't, sorry if the issue already exists!

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you hesitating to use a StatefuWidget when you need one?

Comment: It was a random thought first of all, plus I thought we should be using Stateless Widget for better performance, that's why maybe. (I've a little knowledge since I'm a beginner)

Comment: Use BLoC with events

Comment: That "StatelessWidget for better performance" myth keeps raising its ugly head.

Comment: `StatefuWidget` is as performant as `StatelessWidget`

Answer (score 0):

You can use state-management approaches flutter had provided like Provider, Bloc, Riverpod and many others. Choose one of them and you can manage the state of the widget using stateless widget.